# How do I change the url of the database for Firebase Cloud Function onCreate call on a reference?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Since Firebase does not provide separate databases for debug and production, I decided to create a separate database for testing purposes for my app. I have a firebase function which listens to changes in the database but I'm unable to create a new function which listens to the new database url.

**How can I change the url for the database?**

I tried this :

```
export const sendNotificationTest = functions.database
    .instance("https://appname-1234.firebaseio.com/")
    .ref('/conversations/{conversationID}/{messageID}')
    .onCreate(async (change, context) => {}
```

On trying to deploy, it says

```
HTTP Error: 400, The request has errors
```

Both the databases exist in the same project as shown here -

[image]

Comment: According to the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path) it seems like you're supposed to put the name of the instance, not the URL. So, in the above example, it would be `appname-1234`

Comment: Hi @JenPerson. Thank you so much for that answer! Your solution worked. Can you post the same as a answer so that I can mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#specify_the_database_instance_and_path) it seems like you're supposed to put the name of the instance, not the URL. So, in the above example, it would be `appname-1234`.

Answer (score 1):

With Cloud Functions database triggers, you can only use the database in the same project that's running your functions.  A function can't trigger on databases or other resources that are not in the same project.

The instance() method on the function builder just lets you choose the [shard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding) of your database in the same project, if you've created one.  By default, Realtime Database has just one shard, and you don't need to call it out in your function.  If you have multiple shards, and you want to trigger on one of them specifically, you need to call it out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Doug. Both the databases are in the same project itself. But mentioning the entire url for the database didnt work. So, which part of it should I mention?

Comment: It's worth noting that database shards are *not* intended to segregate dev and prod data.  You're supposed to use different Firebase projects for that.  Sharding is intended for cases where you exceed the capacity of a single database in your project.  You might run into problems with this later.

Comment: Ah I see. Okay. I'll create a separate project for testing. A couple followup q's - 
1. What problems might I run into? 
2. Firebase allows me to add multiple apps into the same project. Hence I've added both my debug and release android apps into the same project. Is it not meant to be done that way?

Comment: You're not supposed to add both debug and release apps to the same project.  Again, you're supposed to use multiple projects - one for each deployment environment.  If you don't do this, you will find it increasingly difficult over time to test your app without impacting your users in production.  It's best to keep things complete separate.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for that info @Doug. I shall create a separate projects for testing.